# Given $\{h\in\mathcal{H}: \left\lVert T^*h\right\rVert=1\}$ is bounded, show that $T$ is invertible.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbertspace, $T:\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}$ a bounded, linear, injective Operator with $R(T)$ dense in $\mathcal{H}$. Given that
$$S=\{h\in\mathcal{H}: \left\lVert T^*h\right\rVert=1\}$$ is bounded, show that $T$ is invertible. ($T^*$ being the adjoint Operator of $T$, $R(T)$ being the image of T)

I am pretty much clueless right here on how to show that, so any hint is appreciated. I am probably misunderstanding something: since $\widetilde{T}:\mathcal{H}\to R(T)$ is bijective and therefore invertible, I need to show this explicitly for $T:\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}$, however I am now missing the surjectiveness of $T$, but since $R(T)$ is dense in $\mathcal{H}$, I can do something about that. The last thing I know, is that the adjoined Operator $T^*$ is injective due to $\{0\}=R(T)^\perp=N(T^*)$, but I don't know if that is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use Banach theorems.

Let $M$ denote the bound of $S.$ Since the range of $T$ is dense, the kernel of $T^*$ is trivial. As $T$ is injective, the range of $T^*$ is dense. The operator $T^*:H\to T^*(H)$ is invertible algebraically. For $u=T^*h$ with $\|u\|=1,$ we get $h\in S,$ thus
$$\|(T^*)^{-1}u\|=\|h\|\le M\quad (*)$$
Equivalently $$\|h\|\le M=M\|T^*h\|$$ which extends by homogeneity to all $h\in H.$ This implies that the range of $T^*$ is closed, hence $T^*(H)=H$ due to the density of $T^*(H).$ By $(*)$ we get that $(T^*)^{-1}:H\to H$ is bounded, i.e. $T^*$ is invertible.  Hence $T$ is invertible.

Answer (score 2):

Hints: If $T^{*}h \neq 0$ then $\|T^{*}h'\|=1$ where $h'=\frac h {\|T^{*}h\|}$. Let $M$ be a bound for $S$. Then $\|h'\|\leq M$ which gives $\|T^{*}h\| \geq \frac1 M \|h\|$. This implies that the range of $T^{*}$ is closed. By Banch's CLosed Range Theoem it follows that range of $T$ is lcosed. But range of $T$ is dense, so $T$ is actually a a bijection. Open Mapping Theorem finishes the proof.